# How can I add column values till a certain value is reached (using select query)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table as below:

```
Date                Bill No     Amount   
24/07/19 12:00:00   43565        20
24/07/19 18:00:00   12354        100
22/07/19 13:20:02   12782        120
22/07/19 15:30:23   99807        200
21/07/19 20:00:23   23686        50
21/07/19 11:34:45   38965        10
21/07/19 10:05:30   04578        45
20/07/19 19:30:00   34950        38
20/07/19 14:25:00   54954        25
```

Starting from sysdate, I want to sum up the amount (back dated) till the sum reaches 500 or close to 500.

When the sum reaches 500, I also want to record the date and time when it reached that value.

I have tried looping through the data but the number of records in the table is huge and it takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to achieve this using select query.

For eg. starting from 24 Jul 2019, I will keep adding the amount -> 20+100+120+200+50+10

This totals to 500 and 500 was reached on 21 Jul 2019 at 11:34:45

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SUM( Amount ) OVER ( ORDER BY "DATE" DESC )` analytic function to get a cumulative total and then you can just filter the rows that have a cumulative total less than 500 and find the greatest row:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( "DATE", Bill_No, Amount ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-07-24' + INTERVAL '12:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, '43565',  20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-24' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, '12354', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-22' + INTERVAL '13:20:02' HOUR TO SECOND, '12782', 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-22' + INTERVAL '15:30:23' HOUR TO SECOND, '99807', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-21' + INTERVAL '20:00:23' HOUR TO SECOND, '23686',  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-21' + INTERVAL '11:34:45' HOUR TO SECOND, '38965',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-21' + INTERVAL '10:05:30' HOUR TO SECOND, '04578',  45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-20' + INTERVAL '19:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND, '34950',  38 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-07-20' + INTERVAL '14:25:00' HOUR TO SECOND, '54954',  25 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           SUM( Amount ) OVER ( ORDER BY "DATE" DESC ) AS total
    FROM   table_name t
  )
  WHERE total <= 500
  OR    ROWNUM = 1   -- Make sure at least one row is returned.
  ORDER BY total DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DATE                | BILL_NO | AMOUNT | TOTAL
> :------------------ | :------ | -----: | ----:
> 2019-07-21 11:34:45 | 38965   |     10 |   500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83f49806f6212c65f4af98ef16888ddb)*